# Cerra pestaña actual con javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito que al pulsar **Salir** se cierre la pestaña o la ventana. Lo que tengo por ahora y sin mucho éxito es esto:

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:close_window();" style="border:none; background-color: #ffffff; width:25%;float:right;cursor:pointer;color:red;text-decoration:none"> Salir </a>
```

**Javascript**

```
function close_window() {
    if (confirm("Seguro que quieres salir?")) {
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Simplemente, sale el mensaje de confirmación y por mucho que le de a **Aceptar** no pasa nada. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que window.close() solo funciona con ventanas que hayan sido abiertas con window.open()

Comment: Muchos usan una especie de hack para que se cierre, ya que lo que menciona camilo es cierto, pon esto `window.open('', '_self', '');` antes de tu `window.close()` a ver si te funciona.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es hacer creer al navegador que la tab actual la abriste con un script, prueba lo siguiente y ponlo en tu `head`:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function cerrar() { 
   window.open('','_parent',''); 
   window.close(); 
} 
</script>
```

Y ya tu link:

```
<a href="javascript:cerrar();">Cerrar</a>
```

Comment: Lo he probado y no funciona. Por consola me sale este warning: 
`busqueda.php:7 Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.`

Comment: @gmarsi Prueba con `_self` en vez de `_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript** solo puede cerrar ventanas que este haya abierto:

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="openWin();">Abrir </button>
<button onclick="closeWin();">Cerrar </button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
  myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
  myWindow.document.write("<p>Esta es mi ventana'</p>");
}

function closeWin() {
  myWindow.close();
}
```

Si te fijas en cada botón llamo a una función que abre o cierra dicha ventana, para ver el funcionamiento revisarlo aca: [Cerrar Ventana JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/1nyxgtra/)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!