# ¿Cómo cerrar la pestaña actual de mi navegador con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero cerrar la pestaña donde me posiciono en mi navegador, escribí esto y aunque el alert se muestra la pestaña no se cierra **(La funcion se encuentra en un archivo externo).**

```
function CerrarPestana()
{
    alert('La ventana Actual se Cerrara');
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: Esa consulta ya se encuentra en stack-overflow.
Mira aquí a ver si pruebas con las posibles soluciones que dan.:

**[Cerrar Pestaña Actual](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110407/cerra-pestaña-actual-con-javascript)**