# ¿Como cerrar la pestaña actual HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, chrome

necesito cerrar la pestaña actual en un proyecto HTML que tengo, necesito que al oprimir un boton me cierre la pestaña.

Ya he intentado con en el .js:

```
self.close();
windows.close();
windows.close(location);
window.open("","_self").close();
window.open(location,"_self").close();
```

y me sale este error

> "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."

¿hay una manera de enviarle al chrome los comandos "ctrl + w" para que el cierre la pestaña actual?

Comment: Al parecer no es posible a menos abras esa pestaña previamente con un open. O bien usando una chrome extension.

Comment: Ya hicieron esa pregunta una vez, la respuesta que con javascrpt solo se pueden cerrar pestañas abiertas por el mismo javascript.

Comment: revisa como reabrir tu proyecto usando javascript. Si es posible(lo hice para un proyecto, lamentablemente ya no trabajo en ese proyecto y por lo tanto no tengo acceso para ayudarte un poco más) pero como te dicen debes abrir la pagina usando javascript y despues la podras cerrar.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Cerra pestaña actual con javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110407/cerra-pesta%c3%b1a-actual-con-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

**Prueba esto:**

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function closed() { 
       window.open('','_parent',''); 
       window.close(); 
    } 
    </script>


<a href="javascript:closed();">Cerrar Pestaña</a>
```

**Ejemplo**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head> 
<title>Cerrar pestaña</title> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function closed() { window.open('','_parent',''); window.close(); }
 </script> 
</head>
 <body>
 <a href="javascript:closed();">Cerrar Pestaña</a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Eso ya lo use, y no sirve

Comment: prueba el codigo de ejemplo que edite la respuesta y dime pq a mi me funciona

Comment: ya probe eso en el js... es mas abri la consola en ejecución y ni aun asi funciono, según leia Chrome deshabilito esa función por seguridad.

Comment: No, no funciona, al menos con chrome 76. Y aunque funcionara, es claro que la intención es eliminar a toda costa esta posibilidad.