# ¿Cómo cerrar pestaña con Window.close?

Tags: javascript, html

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]Estoy intentando cerra una pestaña con `Window.close`, principalmente  tengo un `script` que tiene un `Window.open`, esto lo hice para mostrar la pantalla principal sin las opciones del navegador lo cual funciona, el problema es que queda abierto el proyecto en otra pestaña, ¿Cómo puedo cerrar dicha pestaña que contiene el `link` del proyecto con `Window.close` u otra opción?

Código con el cual le quito las opciones al navegador: con este código le quito las opciones a `index3.php` el cual contiene el `login` del proyecto, ¿cómo puedo desde ahí cerrar el mismo proyecto el cual queda abierto en otra ventana detrás del que se dispara?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.open("index3.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=800, height=600");
            window.close("http://localhost/mirenacer/");//con esto intento cerrar el proyecto que queda abierto, pero no funciona.
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

El proyecto se llama mi renacer,cuando lo abro el bota el login sin opcines del navegador como pueden ever en la segunda foto, pero el link del proyecto queda detras.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se puede cerrar una ventana a menos que la abras programaticamente con open.

Comment: pero yo estoy abriendo el login con windo.open, por que queda abierto todo el proyecto en otra ventana?

Comment: A menos que la otra ventana sea abierta con open, no se puede cerrar programaticamente, el usuario la tiene que cerrar. Todo lo que el usuario abra, lo tiene que cerrar él. La exepcion sería una extensión del navegador. Lo que quizá podrías hacer es no abrir el login aparte, sino en la misma página.

Comment: @Yero considera hacerlo en un modal

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es guardar en una variable la acción del `window.open` y así mismo poder usar el `window.close` de esta manera

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ventana = window.open("index3.php","_blank","toolbar=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=800, height=600");

ventana.window.close();
</script>
```

Algo más o menos así, ojalá te sirva, saludos!!

**Edición**

Agrego que hay una forma de cerrar la pestaña del navegador desde `JavaScript` te la anexo aquí

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open('','_parent',''); 
window.close(); 
</script>
```

Si quieres revisarla mejor, el autor es el de esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/110411/133271)

Te anexo una manera de abrir la ventana para ver sí te funciona y se te visualiza como quieres

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.open("url/", 
        "Inicio de Sesion", "width= 600, height= 600, top= 100, left= 543, menubar= no");
</script>
```

Comment: Hola, con el código que me pasas se cierra la misma ventana que se abrió, osea el login, yo no quiero cerrar esa ventana de login, lo que quiero cerrar es el proyecto que queda en otra ventana después de abrir el login, no se si eso sea posible?dicho proyecto queda como localhost/mirenacer/.

Comment: Osea tienes el navegador abierto y abres esa ventana emergente, y quieres cerrar la pestaña del navegador?

Comment: Quiero que solo se abra el login y que no queden mas pestañas abiertas.la pestaña que queda abierta contieene el link de todo el proyecto.

Comment: Ah, vale, es que lo que hace el window.open es abrir una ventana como cualquier otra, solo que esta es emergente, el va a tomar el funcionamiento normal como sí lo estuvieras manejando en el navegador, sí quieres tener el login a parte, pues tienes que tener la vista sin conectarla con otras vistas, no sé si me entiendas

Comment: @Yero La única forma de lograr ese comportamiento es haciendo una extensión del navegador.

Comment: @Yero Pero pues, sí lo único que quieres es que el login se sobreponga en la pantalla para poder iniciar, pues sería mejor que lo hagas con un modal

Comment: Claro, o bien redirigir directamente a login. Pero Yero quiere que se cierren todas las demás pestañas aparentemente.

Comment: Por lo menos ví un método que desde java script puedes cerrar la pestaña del navegador, ya la agrego a la respuesta con su fuente

Comment: Lo que quería hacer inicialmente era abrir el login sin los opciones del navegador,osea los botones de retroceso y actualizar, con el codigo que coloque logre quitarle las opcines pero se dispara el login por aparte cosa que no quiero.

Comment: ¿Cómo se te dispara?, sí puedes pon un pantallazo

Comment: Y te inserto los pantallazos,dame un omento.

Comment: Osea lo que quieres es que quede en la misma pagina en donde estás haciendo que despliegue el login, sino te estoy entendiendo mal @Yero?

Comment: exacto,que quede ahi mismo con las opciones del navegador bloqueadas, como ya logre bloquerlas no sabia como cerrar la otra pestaña.

Comment: Yo tengo uno parecido, ya te lo agrego a la respuesta a ver que comportamiento tiene

Comment: Ese codigo hace lo mismo que el mio, dispara la ventana del login por aparte.

Comment: Sí quieres vamos a un chat y te ayudo para no alargar tanto los comentarios

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98829/discussion-between-yero-and-daxtter77).